# Are Youtube views accumulated through HTML5 video player Plyr?

Tags: html, youtube, html5-video, embed, plyr.js

I read youtube views does not count if autoplay is on with youtube embed player.

Html5 video player **[Selz/plyr](https://github.com/Selz/plyr)** actually allows you to embed youtube video into their player. I wonder if this plugin accumulates youtube views at all. Can anyone confirm it?

```
<div class="plyrWrapper">
    <div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="AbcdEFghIJ"></div>
</video>


// plyr
window.plyr = plyr;
plyr.setup({
    //options
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, they do count.

Source: https://github.com/Selz/plyr/issues/556